# Empty RecyclerView on launch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-alertdialog

I have added a recyclerview on my fragment. So when the app launches there should be no items in this recyclerview. There is also a fab, which opens a alert dialog in this fragment itself. So when the user inputs some text 2 things should happen -

1)The dialog should close AND 1st item of recyclerview should be created.

2)and the user input text should be displayed in this item's textview.(The model for the recyclerview is already created).

Comment: Please add your code to the question so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your own Adapter and put the text as an item of array there.

Comment: could you provide the code please? I am new to Android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
You can learn RecyclerView here.

Answer (score 0):

Step to achieve this

1. Create array list of your  `ArrayList<String> mListData = new ArrayList<>();`.
2. Add your data in string array like mListData.add("string").
3. Set custom adapter to list
   eg.
   `MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(list) mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`
4. Everytime when user add string add it to mListData and notify data set changed to  adapter.

For more info look. [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)